# Compare vectors and delete vectors where all elements are already inside another vector

Tags: c++, vector, std

I use a vector of vectors to store id-numbers, I would like to compare all of them and delete the elements where all values inside it are already inside another element.

Say i have 4 elements in my vector like this

[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [3], [1,2,3,5]]

In this example the second and third element should be deleted.

What would be the fastest algorithm to solve this?

Comment: I'd advise you to do your own research and show some effort.

Comment: Do you want to get completely rid of duplicates? If yes, a kind of set where all vectors are inserted into might make sense.

Comment: well, I think your question is overly open ended, but to give you a helping hand, std::remove and std::vector::erase are going to be your friends as might std::set_intersect and std::back_inserter. If you get a solution and need help with that we can probably be of more help.

Comment: Are your elements inside vectors sorted?

Comment: "*What would be the fastest algorithm to solve this?*" - The only way to answer that is to run each algorithm in *your* environemtn, on *your* dataset. The best we can do is to suggest algorithms that might be fast, and have you selected the fastest.

Comment: Should an element (3;4) be removed?

Comment: For {1,2,3,4}, {1,2,3}, {3,4}, {1,2,3,5}, which output should be? (note difference in third array)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution.

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::vector<int> VI;
typedef std::vector<std::vector<int>> VVI;

VVI DeleteDups(VVI vvi) {
  std::map<int,int> map;

  for(auto const& vi : vvi)
    for(auto const& i : vi)
      ++map[i];

  vvi.erase(
    std::remove_if(begin(vvi), end(vvi),
      [&map](const VI& vi)->bool {
        for(int i : vi)
          if(map[i] == 1) return false;
        return true;
      }),
    end(vvi));
  return vvi;
}

void Dump(const VVI& vvi) {
  std::cout << "[";
  for(auto const& vi : vvi) {
    std::cout << "[";
    for(int i : vi)
      std::cout << i << ", ";
    std::cout << "], ";
  }
  std::cout << "]\n";
}

int main () {
  Dump(DeleteDups({ {1,2,3,4}, {1,2,3}, {3}, {1,2,3,5} }));
}
```

Comment: std::unordered_map should be faster than std::map.

Comment: "all values inside it are already *inside another element*". I.e. requirenment is not "uniqueness", but "not  
inclusion"

Comment: re: uniqueness. Agreed. But for the sample data given, "not inside another element" and "unique" are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Here solution which fulfills "already inside another element" requirenment, not just "uniqueness" of elements.

For [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [3], [1,2,3,5]], Output is [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1,2,3,5]].

For [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [3,4], [1,2,3,5]], Output is [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1,2,3,5]].

It works as follows:

1. Generate map which maps values to vector of it's containers
2. For each vector, calculate intersections of containers of each value. If more than one item in result intersection(i.e. not only self-intersection), then such vector is removed.

---

```
#include <boost/container/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::assign;
using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

template<typename VecVec,typename OutputIterator>
void delete_included(const VecVec &vv,OutputIterator out)
{
    typedef typename range_value<VecVec>::type vec_type;
    typedef typename const vec_type *vec_id;
    typedef typename range_value<vec_type>::type value_type;

    unordered_map<value_type,container::vector<vec_id> > value_in;
    container::vector<vec_id> all_vec_indexes;
    BOOST_FOREACH(const vec_type &vec,vv)
    {
        all_vec_indexes.push_back(&vec);
        BOOST_FOREACH(const value_type &value,vec)
        {
            value_in[value].push_back(&vec);
        }
    }
    container::vector<vec_id> included_in;
    container::vector<vec_id> intersect;
    BOOST_FOREACH(const vec_type &vec,vv)
    {
        included_in=all_vec_indexes;
        BOOST_FOREACH(const value_type &value,vec)
        {
            intersect.clear();
            set_intersection(included_in,value_in[value],back_inserter(intersect));
            swap(included_in,intersect);
            if(included_in.size()==1)
                break;
        }
        if(included_in.size()==1)
        {
            *out=vec;
            ++out;
        }
    }
}
template<typename VecVec>
void print(const VecVec &vv)
{
    typedef typename range_value<VecVec>::type vec_type;
    typedef typename range_value<vec_type>::type value_type;

    cout << string(16,'_') << endl;
    BOOST_FOREACH(const vec_type &vec,vv)
    {
        copy(vec,ostream_iterator<const value_type&>(cout," "));
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    container::vector<container::vector<int> > vv
    (list_of
        ( list_of (1)(2)(3)(4) )
        ( list_of (1)(2)(3) )
        ( list_of (3) )
        ( list_of (1)(2)(3)(5) )
    );
    print(vv);

    container::vector<container::vector<int> > result;
    delete_included(vv,back_inserter(result));
    print(result);
    return 0;
}
```